# Using Socket.io inside routes with authorization

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I am building a web app where i authorize an user and then give him the option to chat with others . Below is my server.js code for this . Even when i have included e.preventDefault() in my Java script code for the submit button when i hit send the page gets refreshed and my message does not appear there.I tried putting socket io code in server.js outside the route but it is still not working . The code runs fine when it is not associated with any route and no authorization is there . Can anyone please help me out to resolve this?

```js
app.get("/userprofile/chat",ensureAuth, (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
  //connection
  io.on("connection", function(socket){
    console.log("connected")
    socket.on("chatMessage", function(sent_msg){
    sent_msg = "[ " + getCurrentDate() + " ]: " + sent_msg;
    var newMsg=new Chat({msg:sent_msg})
   
    newMsg.save()
     .then(Msg=>{
      socket.broadcast.emit("message",sent_msg);
     })
    .catch(err=>console.log(err))
      
   })
  

})
```

```html
<form id="send-container">
    <input type="text" class="messageinput" required>
    <button type="submit" id="send">Send</button>
</form>
```

```js
 const socket=io();
const messageForm=document.querySelector("#send-container");
const messageInput=document.querySelector(".messageinput");
const container=document.querySelector(".container");


socket.on("message",data=>{
   outputMessage(data);
   container.scrollTop=container.scrollHeight;
})

messageForm.addEventListener("submit",(e)=>{
   e.preventDefault();
   const msg=messageInput.value;
   socket.emit("chatMessage",msg);
   inputMessage(msg);
  container.scrollTop=container.scrollHeight;
   e.target.elements[0].value="";
   e.target.elements[0].focus();


})
```

Answer (score 0):

make your form tag like this

```
<form id="send-container" action="#">
    <input type="text" class="messageinput" required>
    <button type="submit" id="send">Send</button>
</form>
```

this action="#" will make your pervent your form to refresh. you have to test it like that to check if the other things works good if your form won't refresh